# How to make filter which filter members from array?

Tags: angularjs

I have next array:

```
var companies = [
        {
            id:1,
            members : ['alex', 'john','nick']
        },
        {
            id:2,
            members : ['alex', 'john','nick']
        },
        {
            id:3,
            members : ['alex']
        },
        {
            id:3,
            members : ['nick']
        }
    ]
```

I have listend companies in

```
<div ng-repeat=comp in companies |filter: someFilter>{{comp.id}}</div>
```

What I want:
I want to list e.g. only comp where only member 'nick' is? what filter should I write?

I want to list where 'nick' and 'john' are in on array. what to write in filter?
Tried to set filter parameters

```
{members: ["cuan", "john"]}
```

But it doesn't work
Than you in advance.

Comment: you want to list the record where nick is member or where nick and john  both are members?

Comment: I want list 2 cases.separately

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the list in your value (i.e. it's `members` attribute) to see if you can find at least one item matching your filter param:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(value, expected) {
    return value && value.members && (value.members || []).indexOf(expected) >= 0; // this checks if at least one value from members matches the given filter param
  };
})
```

Then use it as such:

```
<div ng-repeat=comp in companies | myfilter:'nick'>{{comp.id}}</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat=comp in companies | myfilter:'nick' | myfilter:'john'>{{comp.id}}</div>
```

Note: that piping them will effectively produce an "AND" effect. Now this is not the most performant result but for small lists it wouldn't be a problem

Alternatively you could allow passing an array as param and do the "AND" check in the filter function - this would be a bit more performant:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(value, expected) {
    return value && value.members && 
       (expected || []).every(function(exp) { return value.members.indexOf(exp) >= 0; }) 
  };
})
```

Then use as:

```
<div ng-repeat=comp in companies | myfilter:['nick','john']>{{comp.id}}</div>
```

Not:e Use `every` for AND, can easily be changed to `some` for an OR effect. You can even parameterize the type of operation, as such:

```
.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(value, type, expected) {
    return value && value.members && 
       (expected || [])[type](function(exp) { return value.members.indexOf(exp) >= 0; }) 
  };
})
```

Then you can use it also for an OR effect:

```
<div ng-repeat=comp in companies | myfilter:'every':['nick','john']>{{comp.id}}</div>

<div ng-repeat=comp in companies | myfilter:'some':['nick','john']>{{comp.id}}</div>
```

Comment: how to pass array as parameter?  Because if I have lots of members how to add lots of "| myfilter:'name'"?

Comment: see edit - explained how you can obtain that and even further customize your filter if you want